# добавить в ветвь реестра через bat файл

Tags: bat, реестр

Как добавить в ветвь реестра HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Word\ параметр «Word» со строковым значением «word value» через запись в bat файле? И как можно добавить саму ветвь HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Word\?

Comment: Лень подгонять под твой вариант, но это разрешает rdp подключения: `reg add "hklm\system\currentcontrolset\control\terminal server" /f /v fDenyTSConnections /t RE
G_DWORD /d 0`